# VSTests - Could not find diagnostic data adapter 'Code Coverage'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage, vstest

I'm new to VS Code Coverage, and I'm trying to use the VSTests tool from the command line (in windows). But i get this error.

```
Warning: Diagnostic data adapter message: Could not find diagnostic data adapter
 'Code Coverage'.  Make sure diagnostic data adapter is installed and try again.
```

Although the tests ran and passed, the `*.coverage` file is nowhere to be found.

Why?

*Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise*

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you figured this out or not yet but I found the following instructions:

Download Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 - Click on "Tools for Visual Studio 2015" and then select "Agents for Visual Studio 2015" from the left navigation bar from (https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

You will see code coverage files along with a bunch of others installed to Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\DataCollectors

Original source:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents

Comment: The Link to old version have changed.
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/

Answer (score 5):

this code coverage tool only ships with MS Visual Studio Enterprise and Ultimate edition. so install it and it will be fix.

Comment: This was the solution for me. I installed enterprise edition and it works