# Problem code coverage in Azure Devops VS test task. .Coverage not created

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, vstest

I'am trying to create a build pipeline in Azure DevOps which contain  a "vs test task". Nothing fancy here. I want to get the code coverage to send it to sonaQube. However, after the pipeline went through the task there is not .Coverage file created.

[image: Error in vs test task]

There is some errors that might be the issue but i'm not sure.
there is a big "Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'", This might be related to the fact that my UnitTestProject.dll is built for Framework 4.6.2 and Platform AnyCPU(for this issue I tried to forced: otherConsoleOptions:/Framework:NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2').

My agent is running on Windows server 2012 and Visual Studio Enterprise everything is up to date:
[VS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wypTq.png)

[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" @C:\Agent_AzureDevOps_1_work_temp\22f8bb11-e53e-11e9-95d5-5bdab8c29281.txt
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.0

My .trx file is created, however, my .coverage file is nowhere to be seen.
I made sure Code Coverage was Enabled.

My package contain those NuGet
[NuGet in my package.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h5A5.png)

I'am blocked and don't know where to look anymore if you guys have an idea.

Thanks for the time. If you guys want more information don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: The logs clearly say "Couldn't find data collector: Code Coverage". Did you do any troubleshooting on that? Is this a private agent or are you using the Microsoft hosted agents? If a private agent, did you verify that the appropriate Visual Studio SKU is installed to allow for code coverage collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTests - Could not find diagnostic data adapter 'Code Coverage'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834219/vstests-could-not-find-diagnostic-data-adapter-code-coverage)

Comment: It's a private agent hosted on a Windows Server 2012.

Comment: VSTests - Could not find diagnostic data adapter 'Code Coverage'. I ve check this post and no. its  not a duplicate.

Comment: So your build server has VS Enterprise installed on it?

Comment: @SébastienHonorine, Please make sure you have only install the visual studio and the workloads you require, the build/test tools. If you have install the build tools, try to remove it.

Comment: @DanielMann yes, as I posted
[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Enterprise\ 
leo Liu what do you mean ? from my pipeline or on the windows server directly? (sorry I'am not very good with all this stuff :/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to add a comment, so I hope this post will not be deleted (although it is not a direct answer, I think). I wanted to suggest you the following:

Do you have an own `*.runsettings` file (where you might have specified a specific  entry? If you do not specify a `*.runsettings` file by yourself, the Azure DevOps vstest@2 Task will use a "default" runsettings file. At least this is what I could observe in the log (`debug=true`)

Hope this helps

BR Michael

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar problem. I run this command :

```
>dotnet test --logger trx "--collect:Code Coverage"
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  MyAPI -> ...\MyApi\bin\Debug\net47\MyAPI.exe
  MyAPI.Tests -> ...\MyAPI.Tests\bin\Debug\net47\MyAPI.Tests.dll
Warning: Update the Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk package reference to version 15.8.0 or later to collect code coverage.
Test run for ...\MyAPI.Tests\bin\Debug\net47\MyAPI.Tests.dll (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.10.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'
Results File: ...\MyAPI.Tests\TestResults\***_2021-09-03_12_02_21.trx

Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:    22, Skipped:     0, Total:    22, Duration: 201 ms - MyAPI.Tests.dll (net47)
```

The .trx is generated, but not the .coverage.

The solution is to add the NuGet package **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk** in the test project.