# Why is Visual Studio Test Task Is Not Able to Create Code Coverage In Azure DevOps?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, code-coverage, azure-pipelines-build-task, vstest.console.exe

I am using Azure DevOps 2020 with self hosted agents. Using this I have created a pipeline for executing asp.net unit test cases using VS test task and have also selected enable code coverage option.

The test cases are getting executed successfully have around 900+ test cases but .coverage file which it is creating is only of 1 KB under the TestResults folder and has nothing in it. I am not sure why is it not creating complete\correct .coverage file?

Is there anything I would need to ask the Development team to add to the Unit Test projects or What can I do to create .coverage file?

I tried the steps mentioned in the another post as well like running PS script and all but still couldn't create any.

[How to generate code coverage report for asp.net unit tests in Azure DevOps build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516073/how-to-generate-code-coverage-report-for-asp-net-unit-tests-in-azure-devops-buil)

[Problem code coverage in Azure Devops VS test task. .Coverage not created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207957/problem-code-coverage-in-azure-devops-vs-test-task-coverage-not-created)

Screenshot of .coverage file created after the VS test task is completed.

[image]

Screenshot of .trx file of test results

[image]

No Code coverage is displayed on Build summary under code coverage section.

[image]